# ManagementObjectSearcher is not defined even after adding System.Management reference in VB2005 Project

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code on the code behind file for a .aspx page in a project:

```
Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT RemoteName FROM win32_NetworkConnection WHERE LocalName = '" & sFilePath.Substring(0, 2) & "'")

    For Each managementObject As ManagementObject In searcher.[Get]()
        Dim sRemoteName As String = TryCast(managementObject("RemoteName"), String)
        sRemoteName += sFilePath.Substring(2)
        Return (New Uri(sRemoteName)).ToString()
    Next

    Return sFilePath
```

The ManagementObjectSearcher and the ManagementObject are both underlined and it is telling me that they are not defined.

I have added the System.Management reference, removed and readded, deleted my cache, rebuilt the whole .aspx page, removed the .dll and numerous other troubleshooting advise I have found on google but still cannot find the answer to this problem.

Please help!

Answer (score 12):

At the top of the project add in the namespace as you would normally:

```
Imports System.Management
```

Then under the project menu at the top (in Visual Studio) select "Add Reference...". Under the ".Net" tab scroll down to "System.Management". Select that line and click OK.

Comment: The problem I was having was that my import statement wasn't working which was fixed by adding the reference manually. I wonder why the reference isn't added automatically by visual studio when I type in an import.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio > Add Reference > Assemblies > select System.Management. this way it will resolve ManagementObjectSearcher and ManagementObjects.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Imports System.Management` to the top of the `.vb` file to allow you to use the class without specifying its [*namespace*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx).

Comment: when I add Imports System.Management to the top I get an error: "Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Management' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one publlic member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases." Not sure what I am supposed to do with that...

Comment: Then you haven't actually referenced the assembly.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, how do I reference the assembly?

Comment: Right-click the project and click Add Reference.

Comment: I have added and removed using that process several times,  I am missing something but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The version of Visual Studio that I have does not import ManagementObjectSearcher by importing "System.Management" namespace.
If you have the same issue, try adding a reference to "System.Management.dll' by doing the following steps.

1. Click on project properties on solution explorer in Visual Studio.
2. Go to "References".
3. Click on "Add" to add a new reference.
4. Click on "Browse...".
5. Navigate to "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727".
6. Add a reference to "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Management.dll".

Answer (score 0):

Before you add the "Imports" to your Class, you have first to add a Reference (to the DLL) to your Project.