# Give a custom name to a process started in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, process, unique

When starting a process in VB.Net, I would like to give it a custom name that can be accessed by any function I give this process to as a argument.

I launch my process this way :

```
Dim mainProcessHandler As New ProcessStartInfo()
Dim mainProcess As Process
mainProcessHandler.FileName = "something_01out18.bat"
mainProcessHandler.Arguments = "-d"
mainProcessHandler.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
mainProcess = Process.Start(mainProcessHandler)
```

If I do nothing more, when using

```
mainProcess.ProcessName
```

I will get "cmd" as it's a bat script run by cmd.

Can I do something like

```
mainProcess.myCustomName = "bat01out18"
```

And call it in a function

```
Sub doThingsWithProcess(ByVal usedForThingsProcess As Process) As Boolean
    infoConsoleDisplay("process " + usedForThingsProcess.myCustomName + " will be used to for things")
End Sub
```

I'm pretty sure there is a way to achieve such thing but maybe with a different approach. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify a process started in VB.Net to be able to kill it and all its children later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164926/identify-a-process-started-in-vb-net-to-be-able-to-kill-it-and-all-its-children)

Comment: You can create a subclass that inherits `Process` and add all the custom properties you want.

Comment: @Blackwood Just looked at the other question and it seems to be asking about something different.

Comment: I mentioned on question 52164926 that using a custom name was a related concern but edited out  **before** opening this question. There is no duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a subclass that inherits from `Process`, then you can add any custom properties you like to it. Here's an example:

```
Public Class CustomProcess
    Inherits Process

    Public Property DisplayName As String

End Class
```

**Usage:**

```
Dim pInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
pInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
pInfo.Arguments = "/C ping 127.0.0.1"
pInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
Dim mainProcess As New CustomProcess() With {.DisplayName = "MyProcess"}
mainProcess.StartInfo = pInfo
mainProcess.Start()

Console.WriteLine($"Process '{mainProcess.DisplayName}' will be doing so and so.")
```

**Output:**

```
Process 'MyProcess' will be doing so and so.
```

Comment: That solved my issue. I set a 
mainProcess.DisplayName = "Process doing that" 
before each                            
mainProcess.StartInfo = mainProcessStartInfo
                            mainProcess.Start()

Comment: @JulienD Exactly, or you can use object initializer (i.e., `With {.DisplayName = "MyProcess"}`) as shown in the answer.

Comment: Sure but as I use the same mainProcess instance several times for different bat scripts, I need to overwrite the DisplayName over time. Thank you.